# How to keep the checkbox checked in DatagridView Checkbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How to make checkbox automatically checked in DataGridview on form load?

Tried to put this code in form load but it does now

```
    Dim chkbox As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    DataGridView4.Columns.Insert(0, chkbox)

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView4.Rows
        Dim cell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = row.Cells(0)

        cell.Value = True
    Next
```

Comment: When you call this code? If you execute it before loading data to the DataGridView, then your code will have no affect

Comment: Where's the rest of your code?  You're adding the column multiple times it seems like.

Comment: I have a datagridview with checkboxcolumn, Once an item is check it will update the Status of the item to "Yes" so  what im trying to achieve is once the item is marked as YES the checkbox will be checked automatically and the checkbox will be disabled (ReadOnly) when i open that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have an empty column 0 then you can do this:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView4.Rows
    row.Cells(0) = New DataGridViewCheckBoxCell With {.Value = True}
Next
```

Comment: it doesnt check automatically when the form is load